# Determining whether a list consist of unique elements

Tags: python

I found some solutions in this forum, but they do not work quite the way I hoped. The following input data is used:

ALY1 ATH BOL BRA
ALY2 ATH BOL BRA
ALY3 ATH BOL BRA
ALY4 ATH BOL BRA
ALY5 BOL BOL BRA
ALY6 ATH BOL BRA BOL

I want to keep only lines 1,2,3, and 4. But not 5 and 6, as here duplicates occur. The following is what I used:

```
f_groups = open(args[1], "r")
f_idl_group = open(args[2], "w")
def allUnique(x):
    seen = set()
    return not any(i in seen or seen.add(i) for i in x)

for line in f_groups :
    line_elements = line.split()
    identifyers = line_elements[0:]
    if allUnique(identifyers) :
        print("all is well" + identifyers[0])
        #write to file
```

Using the script as above, all lines pass, but using :

```
if not allUnique(identifyers) :
```

Then only lines 5 and 6 pass.
The latter is what I would expect, but I want the opposite, only to pass lines 1, 2, 3, and 4. Which fails.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Easiest way to see if a list has all unique elements is to use `len(x) == len(set(x))`.  The `set` will remove any duplicates, then just see if the element count changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def allUnique(x):
    return len(x) == len(set(x))
```

This will return `True` if all elements in list `x` are unique, otherwise `False`.  `set(x)` is a set of the elements of `x`, with any duplicates removed.  If it has the same element count as `x`, then there were no duplicates.  Otherwise there were.

Comment: I tried it, but still all 6 lines pass, but emptying the last two sets. If I write results to a file, then this is waht I get:
['ALY1', 'ATH', 'BOL', 'BRA']['ALY2', 'ATH', 'BOL', 'BRA']['ALY3', 'ATH', 'BOL', 'BRA']['ALY4', 'ATH', 'BOL', 'BRA'][][].
Using the if not allUnique then I get the last two lines.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If you post the code you're using, I can tell you what's going wrong, but it clearly isn't this function.  Your posted code is only printing "all is well" plus the first element of the list, so it can't possibly be doing what you claim here.

Comment: In the absence of seeing your code, all I can suggest is that, when `allUnique` returns `False`, you are writing an empty list to your file.  You instead want to skip the the row entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the entire code I use:
    #! python  
    import sys    
    args = sys.argv    
    f_groups = open(args[1], "r")      
    f_idl_group = open(args[2], "w")  
    def allUnique(x):  
         seen = set()  
    return not any(i in seen or seen.add(i) for i in x)      
for line in f_groups :  
     line_elements = line.split()    
     identifyers = line_elements[0:]  
     if allUnique(identifyers) :  
      print("all is well" )  
      f_idl_group.write(str(line_elements))

Comment: Here's another possibility:  You may have some blank lines at the end of your file.  If so, they will qualify as having all unique elements, and they will be printed as empty lists.  So perhaps you just need to add a check for blank lines, i.e. `len(x) == 0`.  Skip the line if it's blank.

Comment: The blank lines indeed caused the problem!